# GSAP SVG Animation - Firefox glitch

Tags: firefox, animation, svg, gsap

I am working on an animation using GSAP and it is working perfectly on both Chrome and IE, Firefox however has the following glitches:

1. When the cup fill color fills up the color disappears as opposed to staying there. What looks as if the animation reverts to its original state.
2. While the big gear rotates around its center the other two seem to rotate around 0,0.

The animation can be found at:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxJQQr

```
<code>
```

Any help or leads would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: IE and Chrome are incorrectly defaulting to transform-box: fill-box. I'm not sure you can override that. You can't override Firefox's implementation to fill-box so all you can do is ensure that the fill-box and view-box are the same. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box

Comment: Answered in the GreenSock forums: http://greensock.com/forums/topic/14799-a-few-questions/ (had to do with bugs in Firefox and IE, workarounds in link)

Comment: You've not discovered any bugs in Firefox, but you have found bugs in other UAs as I've explained in the forum.